# Use local image on django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I wrote an image upload form which handles file and URL uploads. This is a model form which commits to the database an unpublished image.

```
class UnpublishedImage(Model(20)):
    picture = ImageField(help_text=_('Unpublished picture'), upload_to=settings.UNPUBLISHED_PICTURE_UPLOAD_TO)
```

That Model(20) gives each model a pid field (20 random slug chars), which I use as a public ID for my models.

The unpublished images work just fine, but now I want to use them, that is, I want to publish them.

```
class Look(Model(20)):
    user = OneToOneField(get_user_model(), editable=False)
    title = CharField(max_length=40)
    description = TextField(max_length=160)
    #image = OneToOneField(UnpublishedImage)
```

To make this clear, it works in two steps:

1. The user uploads an image (unpublished)
2. The next form shows the image and allows to add a description, title, etc.

Now, I can't use OneToOneField to the UnpublishedImage model because I want to delete it from the unpublished table (and storage) as soon as the image is published. How do you recommend doing this?

I have tried ImageField, but I don't know how to give the image to the form.

Note that there's a third form for retrieving unpublished images, so you can use that.

```
class UnpublishedImagePublishForm(Form):
    image = CharField()

    def clean_image(self):

        # Get the unpublished object
        try:
            unpublished = UnpublishedImage.objects.get(pid=self.cleaned_data['image'])
        except UnpublishedImage.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(_("Image not found"))

        return unpublished
```

This way I can get the image:

```
    # Get the unpublished image
    unpublished = UnpublishedImagePublishForm(request.DATA)
    if not unpublished.is_valid():
        return Response(unpublished.errors, status=HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    # Get the unpublished image instance
    image = unpublished.cleaned_data['image']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get this straight, you want to upload a picture. Look at it and than confirm it.
Where do you finally want to save the picture. Which model?

Comment: This was a while back, but no. I had picture uploads. What I was trying to do was an "upload first, confirm upload after" scheme, if that is perceptible at all. That is, the picture gets upload so that the picture is displayed while the user is filling some other data. Think how sites like facebook work. So, first the picture is uploaded and save in local storage with an URL pointer in the UnpublishedImage model. Upon form submit, the temporary storage is deleted and a permanent one created. If the form upload expires, the temporary storage is deleted. I solved this, just don't remember how.